# Exchange 2010 can't find SSL certificate that exists

Tags: exchange-2010, ssl-certificate, pop3, x509

I'm trying to set up TLS for the POP3 server in the Exchange CAS role.

I purchased a cert from NameCheap, and the CA path is fully trusted, and installed it within the Certificates MMC snap-in without any trouble.

However Exchange 2010 doesn't seem to like it: I see this in the event viewer:

> Event ID: 2007
>   Source: MSExchangePOP3
>   A certificate for the host name "mail.mydomain.net" couldn't be found. SSL or TLS encryption can't be made to the POP3 service.

...despite the fact that such a certificate does exist:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ExchangeCertificate

Thumbprint                                Services   Subject
----------                                --------   -------
DAFFAE2391F40412386DCFC3AC8E822AAE181312  .P.W..     CN=mail.mydomain.net, OU=PositiveSSL, OU=Domain Control Validated
1C363A4D6A40921230BBD02C47A3260863D05CAA  I...S.     CN=machineName
BCSH281A051860123D70C0BD2E1EB6DBABDC98DD  ......     CN=WMSvc-MACHINENAME
```

I've started the server (and services) numerous times. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was just a random glitch. I went back to NameCheap and re-issued the certificate using the same steps as before. After I imported it into Exchange I was able to secure POP3 without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the certificate enabled and installed for POP3 services.  You could try a to rerun Enable-ExchangeCertificate.  I'm assuming you requested the certificate with New-ExchangeCertificate, which if not may be worthwhile for a clean Exchange certificate retry.

However, there are issues where the certificate in question can have certain problems that make Exchange 2010 fail.  Try to use the self-signed default certificate to test temporarily and/or have NameCheap re-issue the certificate.  Ref: [Error ID 2007 Exchange 2010](http://www.outlookforums.com/threads/9115-weird-issue-pop3-certificates/)

If I'm way off please post details of Get-ExchangeCertificate DAFFAE2391F40412386DCFC3AC8E822AAE181312 | fl